# Ext.dataview.component.DataItem descendant with a complex UI

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am creating a custom DataItem that will raise events when tapped.

The example on page http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2 is pretty ok but I couldn't find a way to create a complex ui for the item. The sample has an hbox layout and creates the controls in it. My dataitem also has an hbox layout but on the far right I have to lay three buttons in a vbox layout. Do I have to create another control for the vbox and the buttons in it?

I dont' want to catch DOM events, I want to do it the Sencha Touch way.

Thanks.

Comment: can u provide a snap of layout you seek ?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to create. The main item is an hbox with an image, panel and vbox in it. The vbox will have buttons all of which will raise events. http://snag.gy/F9PhZ.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a demo to sencha fiddle. It might give you an idea on how to proceed. Here is the [link](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#HWu1K).