# How to add a button in data view list in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I want to add a Sencha Touch button in data view list and some function will call on tap event of that button

like this :

ITEM 1 BUTTON 1
ITEM 2 BUTTON 2
ITEM 3 BUtton 3

Comment: If you want it, go for it! Whats the problem? [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far?

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909461/ext-dataview-component-dataitem-descendant-with-a-complex-ui

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DataItem: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.component.DataItem

```
// The dataview
Ext.define('MyDataView', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
    config: {
        defaultType: 'mydataitem',
        useComponents: true
    }
});

// The dataitem
Ext.define('MyDataItem', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    alias: 'widget.mydataitem',
    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            flex: 1,
            html: 'val1',
            itemId: 'textCmp'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',  
            text: 'Val2'
        }]
    },
    updateRecord: function(record) {
        this.down('#textCmp').setHtml(record.get('val1'));
        this.down('button').setText(record.get('val2'));

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```